# Is it possible to use different server to developed Text chat & Voice call?

Tags: android, chat, voip, sinch

I am already developed a chat(One to one & Group) APP using openfire XMPP server. Now I want to integrate voice and video call in this app. Is it possible to use different server to developed Text chat & Voice call? if yes then how it possible?

Can I use Sinch server beside openfire XMPP server in a single app. Openfire for normal text chat & Sinch or any other for Audio and Video calling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not? Integrate their SDK and thats it.

Comment: @GoneUp But I already use another SDK for implementation text chating. I want confirmation that there is no Syncing problem between two server if I use their SDK.

Comment: Whichever XMPP and WebRTC configuration you use, there will be no problem. You can use alltogether.